# Compiling with nvcc using g++ and additional root libraries results in "undefined references" or "unrecognized command line option"

Tags: shared-libraries, nvcc

I just started with cuda and nvcc and cannot progress beyond this particular problem. I would greatly appreciate help.

For the minimal example I have three files:
main.cpp

```
#include "myClass.hh"

int main()
{
    myClass temp;
    return 0;
}
```

myClass.hh

```
#include "TTree.h" //can be replaced by any root class

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass() = default;
};
```

and myClass.cu

```
#include "myClass.hh"

__global__ void myCudaFunction(){};

myClass::myClass() { myCudaFunction<<<1, 1>>>(); }
```

which I am compiling with

```
`nvcc -ccbin g++ -o a.out main.cpp myClass.cu -Xcompiler="-L/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib" -Xcompiler="-lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -lROOTDataFrame -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic" --linker-options="-rpath,/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib" -Xcompiler="-I$(root-config --incdir)" `
```

but this returns the error:

```
`/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/include/TStorage.h:131:37: warning: declaration of ‘static void TStorage::UpdateIsOnHeap(const volatile UInt_t&, volatile UInt_t&)’ with attribute ‘noinline’ follows inline declaration [-Wattributes]
 R__NEVER_INLINE void TStorage::UpdateIsOnHeap(volatile const UInt_t &uniqueID, volatile UInt_t &bits) {
                                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/include/TStorage.h:91:20: note: previous declaration of ‘static void TStorage::UpdateIsOnHeap(const volatile UInt_t&, volatile UInt_t&)’ was here
    static void UpdateIsOnHeap(volatile const UInt_t &uniqueID, volatile UInt_t &bits);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/tmpxft_0000d4e8_00000000-8_main.o: in function     `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/tmpxft_0000d4e8_00000000-11_myClass.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tmpxft_0000d4e8_00000000-5_myClass.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to  `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

.

Usually the problem with this is, that a library is missing, that is why I copy and pasted the output of

`main_user@Notebook:~/cudaTest$ root-config --libs -L/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -lROOTDataFrame -Wl,-rpath,/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic`
.
The output of the other variable is

`main_user@Notebook:~/cudaTest$ root-config --incdir /home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/include`

and I have only one ROOT installation.

My suspicion is, that the error is related to

`-Wl,-rpath,/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib`

, but if I use

`-Xcompiler="$(root-config --libs)"`

instead, I get

`main_user@Notebook:~/cudaTest$ nvcc -ccbin g++ -o a.out main.cpp myClass.cu -Xcompiler="$(root-config --libs)" -Xcompiler="-I$(root-config --incdir)"  g++-8: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’; did you mean ‘-W’? g++-8: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath’`
.

I also tried to rearrange the input, but without success. I have also read, that not all library files are suitable for nvcc. It seems only .so files are permissible, so here is the check:

`main_user@Notebook:~/cudaTest$ ls /home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib/ ASImageGui.pcm                   libcomplexDict.rootmap       libmapDict.rootmap             libRooFitHS3.so                    libXMLParser.so               libXrdSecProt-5.so       Recorder.pcm ASImage.pcm                      libcomplexDict.so            libmapDict.so                  libRooFitMore.so                   libXrdAppUtils.so             libXrdSecpwd-5.so        RGL.pcm _Builtin_intrinsics.pcm          libCore.so                   libMathCore.so                 libRooFitMultiProcess.so           libXrdAppUtils.so.2           libXrdSecsss-5.so        RHTTP.pcm _Builtin_stddef_max_align_t.pcm  libc.pcm                     libMathMore.so                 libRooFitRDataFrameHelpers.so      libXrdAppUtils.so.2.0.0       libXrdSecunix-5.so       RHTTPSniff.pcm Cling_Runtime_Extra.pcm          libcppyy3_8.so               libMatrix.so                   libRooFit.so                       libXrdBlacklistDecision-5.so  libXrdServer.so          Rint.pcm Cling_Runtime.pcm                libcppyy_backend3_8.so       libMinuit2.so                  libRooFitZMQ.so                    libXrdBwm-5.so                libXrdServer.so.3        RIO.pcm cmdLineUtils.py                  libdequeDict.rootmap         libMinuit.so                   libRooStats.so                     libXrdCksCalczcrc32-5.so      libXrdServer.so.3.0.0    RMPI.pcm Core.pcm                         libdequeDict.so              libMLP.so                      libRootAuth.so                     libXrdClProxyPlugin-5.so      libXrdSsi-5.so           RMySQL.pcm cppyy                            libEG.so                     libmultimap2Dict.rootmap       libROOTDataFrame.so                libXrdCl.so                   libXrdSsiLib.so          RooFitCore.pcm cppyy_backend                    libEve.so                    libmultimap2Dict.so            libROOTPythonizations3_8.so        libXrdCl.so.3                 libXrdSsiLib.so.2        RooFitHS3.pcm DistRDF                          libFFTW.so                   libmultimapDict.rootmap        libROOTTMVASofie.so                libXrdCl.so.3.0.0             libXrdSsiLib.so.2.0.0    RooFitMore.pcm EG.pcm                           libFitPanel.so               libmultimapDict.so             libROOTTPython.so                  libXrdCmsRedirectLocal-5.so   libXrdSsiLog-5.so        RooFit.pcm Eve.pcm                          libFITSIO.so                 libMultiProc.so                libROOTVecOps.so                   libXrdCryptoLite.so           libXrdSsiShMap.so        RooFitRDataFrameHelpers.pcm FFTW.pcm                         libFoam.so                   libmultisetDict.rootmap        libSessionViewer.so                libXrdCryptoLite.so.2         libXrdSsiShMap.so.2      RooStats.pcm FitPanel.pcm                     libforward_listDict.rootmap  libmultisetDict.so             libsetDict.rootmap                 libXrdCryptoLite.so.2.0.0     libXrdSsiShMap.so.2.0.0  ROOT FITSIO.pcm                       libforward_listDict.so       libNet.so                      libsetDict.so                      libXrdCrypto.so               libXrdThrottle-5.so      RootAuth.pcm Foam.pcm                         libFumili.so                 libNetxNG.so                   libSmatrix32.rootmap               libXrdCrypto.so.2             libXrdUtils.so           ROOT_Config.pcm Fumili.pcm                       libGdml.so                   libNew.so                      libSmatrix.so                      libXrdCrypto.so.2.0.0         libXrdUtils.so.3         ROOTDataFrame.pcm Gdml.pcm                         libGed.so                    libPhysics.so                  libSpectrumPainter.so              libXrdCryptossl-5.so          libXrdUtils.so.3.0.0     ROOT_Foundation_C.pcm Ged.pcm                          libGenetic.so                libPostscript.so               libSpectrum.so                     libXrdFfs.so                  libXrdXml.so             ROOT_Foundation_Stage1_NoRTTI.pcm Genetic.pcm                      libGenVector32.rootmap       libProofBench.so               libSPlot.so                        libXrdFfs.so.3                libXrdXml.so.3           ROOT_Rtypes.pcm GenVector.pcm                    libGenVector.so              libProofDraw.so                libSQLIO.so                        libXrdFfs.so.3.0.0            libXrdXml.so.3.0.0       ROOTTMVASofie.pcm GeomBuilder.pcm                  libGeomBuilder.so            libProofPlayer.so              libSrvAuth.so                      libXrdFileCache-5.so          libXrdXrootd-5.so        ROOTTPython.pcm GeomPainter.pcm                  libGeomPainter.so            libProof.so                    libThread.so                       libXrdHttp-5.so               MathCore.pcm             ROOTVecOps.pcm Geom.pcm                         libGeom.so                   libPyMVA.so                    libTMVAGui.so                      libXrdHttpUtils.so            MathMore.pcm             SessionViewer.pcm Gpad.pcm                         libGpad.so                   libQuadp.so                    libTMVA.so                         libXrdHttpUtils.so.2          Matrix.pcm               Smatrix.pcm Graf3d.pcm                       libGraf3d.so                 libRCsg.so                     libTreePlayer.so                   libXrdHttpUtils.so.2.0.0      Minuit2.pcm              SpectrumPainter.pcm Graf.pcm                         libGraf.so                   libRecorder.so                 libTree.so                         libXrdN2No2p-5.so             Minuit.pcm               Spectrum.pcm GuiBld.pcm                       libGuiBld.so                 libRGL.so                      libTreeViewer.so                   libXrdOfsPrepGPI-5.so         MLP.pcm                  SPlot.pcm GuiHtml.pcm                      libGuiHtml.so                libRHTTPSniff.so               libUnfold.so                       libXrdOssCsi-5.so             modules.idx              SQLIO.pcm Gui.pcm                          libGui.so                    libRHTTP.so                    libunordered_mapDict.rootmap       libXrdOssSIgpfsT-5.so         modules.timestamp        std.pcm Gviz3d.pcm                       libGviz3d.so                 libRint.so                     libunordered_mapDict.so            libXrdPfc-5.so                MultiProc.pcm            Thread.pcm GX11.pcm                         libGX11.so                   libRIO.so                      libunordered_multimapDict.rootmap  libXrdPosixPreload.so         Net.pcm                  TMVAGui.pcm GX11TTF.pcm                      libGX11TTF.so                libRMPI.so                     libunordered_multimapDict.so       libXrdPosixPreload.so.2       NetxNG.pcm               TMVA.pcm HistFactory.pcm                  libHistFactory.so            libRMySQL.so                   libunordered_multisetDict.rootmap  libXrdPosixPreload.so.2.0.0   Physics.pcm              Tree.pcm HistPainter.pcm                  libHistPainter.so            libRooBatchCompute_AVX2.so     libunordered_multisetDict.so       libXrdPosix.so                Postscript.pcm           TreePlayer.pcm Hist.pcm                         libHist.so                   libRooBatchCompute_AVX512.so   libunordered_setDict.rootmap       libXrdPosix.so.3              ProofBench.pcm           TreeViewer.pcm Html.pcm                         libHtml.so                   libRooBatchCompute_AVX.so      libunordered_setDict.so            libXrdPosix.so.3.0.0          ProofDraw.pcm            Unfold.pcm Imt.pcm                          libImt.so                    libRooBatchCompute_CUDA.so     libvalarrayDict.rootmap            libXrdPss-5.so                Proof.pcm                X3d.pcm JsMVA                            libJupyROOT3_8.so            libRooBatchCompute_GENERIC.so  libvalarrayDict.so                 libXrdSec-5.so                ProofPlayer.pcm          XMLIO.pcm JupyROOT                         liblistDict.rootmap          libRooBatchCompute.so          libvectorDict.rootmap              libXrdSecgsi-5.so             __pycache__              XMLParser.pcm libASImageGui.so                 liblistDict.so               libRooBatchCompute_SSE4.1.so   libvectorDict.so                   libXrdSecgsiAUTHZVO-5.so      PyMVA.pcm libASImage.so                    libmap2Dict.rootmap          libRooFitCommon.so             libX3d.so                          libXrdSecgsiGMAPDN-5.so       Quadp.pcm libCling.so                      libmap2Dict.so               libRooFitCore.so               libXMLIO.so                        libXrdSeckrb5-5.so            RCsg.pcm`

I was crosschecking the spelling, rearranging the arguments and googling. I tried to include the library path with `--linker-options="-rpath,/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib"` as well as with `Xcompiler`.
Can you help me with this problem, please?

Edit:
The solution in https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-error-while-linking-with-nvcc/46476/3 did not work for me either ('g++-8: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’; did you mean ‘-W’?'). Could the problem be, that nvcc uses g++-8, while g++ 9.4.0 is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `-Xcompiler "$(root-config --libs)"` with `--linker-options "-L/home/main_user/Tools/ROOT/install/lib -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -lROOTDataFrame -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic"`, so without the -Wl part of root-config --libs, seems to work.